# Django REST Framework Serializer Initialize variable in init

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to initialize a django model's object inside a Serializer class. Lets say I have 2 models ABCD and WXYZ. I performed a filter on ABCD and send the results to a serializer. The serializer need to get an instance of WXYZ model using a field of ABCD model, and fetch some result. I want to get the WXYZ instance in the init method, so that I can access that across all functions in the serializer class.
Models:

```
class ABCD():
    col1 = models.Integerfield(...)
    ...

class WXYZ():
    col2 = models.Integerfield(...)
    title = models.Charfield(...)
    ...
```

views.py:

```
# performed a filter on ABCD model
abcd_objects = ABCD.objects.filter(...)
results = ABCDserializer(abcd_objects, many=True).data
```

serialzers.py

```
class ABCDserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.SerializerMethodField('fetch_title')
    ...

    def __init__(self, obj):
        ans = WXYX.objects.get(col2=obj.col1)
        self.wxyz_obj = ans

    def fetch_title(self, obj):
        return self.wxyz_obj.title

    class Meta:
        model = ABCD
        fields = ['title', ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't override the `__init__` of the serializer; look up the related wxyz in e.g. a property using `self.instance`.

```
class ABCDserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.SerializerMethodField("fetch_title")

    # TODO: Use `functools.cached_property` if on Python 3.8+
    @property
    def _related_wxyz(self):
        return WXYZ.objects.get(col2=self.instance.col1)

    def fetch_title(self, obj):
        return self._related_wxyz.title

    class Meta:
        model = ABCD
        fields = ["title", ...]
```

(This will need to make N extra queries, of course; if that is a problem, you could optimize this by prefetching the WXYZes for each ABCD so the serializer doesn't need to, but that's more involved and really a separate question.)

Comment: If I call ```self._related_wxyz``` many times, will it affect the performance as the call will hit the DB as many times?

Comment: As my post says, yes. Since you're not foreign keys (or related fields in general), Django can't help you automatically reduce that (you could otherwise use e.g. `prefetch_related("wxyz")`).

Comment: If I'll change the ```col1 = models.Integerfield(...)``` to ```ForeignKey(WXYZ)``` in  model ```ABCD```. How will django behave after migrations, if say, for some entries it could not link the field to the ```WXYZ``` model?

Comment: If the field already has a value that has no matching WXYZ, the migration will fail (if your RDBMS checks foreign keys, as it should).